# Contact Form 7 Conditional redirect

Tags: javascript, plugin-contact-form-7

As per [this ticket](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/request-for-multiple-external-redirects/) on WordPress forum, I have added the below code to my contact form for conditional redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
inputs = event.detail.inputs;
inputs.forEach( function(el) {
    if ( el.name == "menu-52" ) {
        if ( el.value == "Below $10,000" ) {
            location.href = "https://www.facebook.com";
        } else if ( el.value == "Above $10,000" ) {
            location.href = "https://google.co.in";
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

But this is not working for me on my contact form and there are some errors on the console also.

Can someone please have a look and let me know where I am making mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you added this code? It is an event listener part and should be added through "Redirect Settings" tab of contact form settings, see [screenshot](https://ps.w.org/wpcf7-redirect/assets/screenshot-1.png).

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer. We need to grab the code inside the Event Listener code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
inputs = event.detail.inputs;
inputs.forEach( function(el) {
    if ( el.name == "menu-52" ) {
        if ( el.value == "Below $10,000" ) {
            location.href = "https://www.facebook.com";
        } else if ( el.value == "Above $10,000" ) {
            location.href = "https://google.co.in";
        }
    }
});
}, false );
</script>
```

Thank you.